# Google Chart Data Grouping

Tags: google-visualization

I want a feature for my Google Chart. Such that, if the number of series is greater than a specified number, the remaining series will be grouped together into one series.

For example, I have 5 series of fruits: Apple, Banana, Orange, Mango, Avocado
And my series limit is 3.

My graph will show: Apple, Banana, Orange, Others.

What happened is that the remaining series (Mango and Avocado) were grouped together into 'Others'.

Does Google Charts have a feature for this (e.g: aggregators probably) ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group or join may help. If not, you would need to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataView to combine your extra columns into one:

```
// assumes you have a DataTable "data" with 6 columns (one domain, plus your 5 fruits)
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, {
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Others',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        // combine columns 4 and 5 together:
        return dt.getValue(row, 4) + dt.getValue(row, 5);
    }
}]);
```